# How to delete index in elasticsearch 5.6.3

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I have recently update elasticsearch version in my project from 2.3.3 to 5.6.3 ,In 2.3.3 version i was using org.elasticsearch.plugin 2.0.0-rc1 for delete my index and i was working with following setting:-

```
      Client client = TransportClient.builder().addPlugin(DeleteByQueryPlugin.class).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port));
```

And my delete index code are:-

```
        DeleteByQueryResponse response = new DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client, DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
                .setIndices(index)
                .setTypes(indexType)
                .setSource(query.toString())
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

But in elasticsearch version 5.6.3  i have using following approach  to delete index are:-

```
 BulkByScrollResponse response = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
                .source(index)
                .filter(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query.toString()))
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

But when i ran my code i have got following exception:-

**java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: V_5_1_1_UNRELEASED**

Please suggest how can i delete index with elastic search 5.6.3 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the recommended option from elastic's [website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.6/java-docs-delete-by-query.html)

Comment: I can see some diffs that's why I sent the link